# Swift, Hero Transition Framework crash on self.isHeroEnabled = true

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewanimationtransition

The app crashes when enabling **Hero Framework** in destination ViewController whether it was set through the code or storyboard. What could be the reason?

Console says:

> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSArray0 objectAtIndex:]: index 0 beyond bounds for empty NSArray'

The shown error in code is:

```swift
if (view as? UINavigationBar) == nil {
    // the Snapshot's contentView must have hold the cornerRadius value,
    // since the snapshot might not have maskToBounds set

    let contentView = snapshot.subviews[0]  // Error, index goes out of bounds here

    contentView.layer.cornerRadius = view.layer.cornerRadius
    contentView.layer.masksToBounds = true
}
```

Why exactly does it happen?

Comment: As it says, `snapshot.subviews` is empty. Not clear from your code what `snapshot` is. You can add a check to make sure the array is not empty to avoid the crash.

Comment: I don't understand what snapshot means exactly myself. It is part of Hero framework.

Comment: it's possible that you're calling this before subviews added to snapshot hierarchy, can you please let us know where you're setting `isHeroEnabled` ?

Comment: I tried adding isHeroEnabled through storyboard as "User Defined Runtime Attributes", in viewDidLoad(), viewDidAppear() and viewWillAppear().

Comment: My only guess at the moment is that the framework was originally written without Storyboard in mind (i.e. adding subviews to the superview in code)